# nginx location regex not matching url

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

guys ,my nginx location conf file is here:

```
       location ~  ^(.*)event(.*)$ {
                return 777;
        }
```

and ,mu url is

```
aaa.com/index.php?r=event/indexpage&a=1&b=2
```

but ,its not  working , plx help me , thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `location` directive cannot match against the query string.

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

> Note that locations of all types test only a URI part of request line
> without arguments. This is done because arguments in the query string
> may be given in several ways..

You can check the query string inside the `location` directive though.

```
location / {
  if ($query_string ~ /^(.*)event(.*)$/) {
    return 777;
  }
}
```

You can also use a `map` to perform the match.

```
map $query_string $has_event {
  ~^(.*)event(.*)$ 1;
  default          0;
}

...

location / {
  if ($has_event) {
    return 777;
  }
}
```

If you use this method be sure to put the `map` directive in the right context, it can only live in the `http` context.

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html

Comment: wooooo~ its done , thx bro ~